# How to use rails_admin with mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, rails-admin

My project has 2 ORMs (activerecord and mongoid) i want to use admin panel for mongoid models.
I had defined single model for admin panel.

```
config.included_models = ['Destination']
```

Now i am getting error.

```
NameError in RailsAdmin::MainController#index
uninitialized constant RailsAdmin::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Association
Extracted source (around line #53):

            # If the constant was actually loaded, something else went wrong?
            raise if from_mod.const_defined?(const_name)
            CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }
          end

          # Signature has changed a few times over the years; easiest to not
```

I guess it is treating this model as activerecord model. 
Is there any one who is using mongoid with rails_admin and help me out in this?
If possible please share source code configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution by adding

```
require 'rails_admin/adapters/active_record'
```

to config/initializers/rails_admin.rb(since mounted on /rails_admin path).

Now it's working as expected.